# TypeScript class member shorthand bug?

Tags: constructor, typescript

As I have played around with the TypeScript language, I got confused by the bahaviour of the **class member shorthand syntax** together with **inheritance**. Say you have the following valid TypeScript with two semantic intendical classes and an interface with one property:

```
    class Person1 implements HasName {
      constructor(public name: string) {}
    }

    class Person2 implements HasName {
      public name : string;
      constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
      }
    }

    interface HasName {
      name : string;
    }
```

Now if you try to rename the 'name' property in the HasName interface, only the member in Person2 will be correctly renamed and in Person1 you will get an TypeScript error saying, that it doesnt implement HasName anymore.

With this behaviour in place, it won't be possible to safely use the shorthand syntax for class members :-/

Is this a **bug** or **intended**? As far as I'm concerned, a **refactoring operation** should never ever result in a compiler **error**. It should instead rename the short hand member in Person1 as well, which sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 3):

If what you describe is true then I agree that it is a bug. But you have to distinguish between a language and a plugin to visual studio. Your bug is in the refactoring part of visual studio plugin not in the language itself. Note that there is a lot of bugs not implemented features as latest release (0.8.0) is an alpha.

Comment: +1 - the compiler correctly identifies this, so there is no bug in the TypeScript language or compiler.

Comment: I didn't use visual studio, i just played around on the typescript playground on their page. Also if you click on the name field in the HasName interface, you will see that the name field in Person1 doesn't get highlighted like the other name members do.

Comment: This is the same thing. What you are describing is a tool that is written to do refactoring the only difference is that it is in browser. It is a bug but not in language nor compiler.